# .htaccess to change the query string

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This is my URL:

```
localhost/myweb/home.php
```

now I just removed the file extension using this code:

```
RewriteEngine on  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

and turn to this:

```
localhost/myweb/home
```

and it works fine.

Now I want to change this URL:

```
localhost/myweb/home.php?str=tmprow
```

to this:

```
localhost/myweb/home/tmprow
```

Comment: Why can't you do the same thing again?

Comment: what do you mean? how?

Answer (score 1):

You may try something like this:

```php
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?([^/]+)?/?  $1.php?str=$2  [L,NC]
```

Maps silently

`http://localhost/myweb/par1` or

`http://localhost/myweb/par1/par2` with or without trailing slash

To:

`http://localhost/myweb/par1.php` or

`http://localhost/myweb/par1.php?str=par2`

Set `RewriteBase` to `/myweb` if necessary, according to actual setting and `DocumentRoot`.

All strings are assumed to be variable while `myweb` is assumed to be fixed.

For permanent redirection, replace `[L,NC]` with `[R=301,L,NC]`